# What about political philosophy?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Bearing in mind that there is a philosophy stack, I still wonder if questions of political philosophy would be on topic here. One such question might be:

> With respect to Nozick's philosophy of just distributions of property being the result of previously just distributions and just processes, could any distribution of property in the Americas be considered just since there is a history of injust taking of property from native Americans?

I guess an expansion of my meta question might be whether questions here should primarily be about actual real world situations, policies, people, history, etc, and not about hypotheticals.

Edit:

I notice a hypothetical question that has been open for two days, so perhaps hypotheticals are okay or even good here:
[Does Gibbard–Satterthwaite theorem apply to all voting systems?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14015/does-gibbard-satterthwaite-theorem-apply-to-all-voting-systems)

Comment: The last example isn't a "hypothetical". It's straight up political science theory, done the right way. "hypothetical" usually refers to practical questions framed as "what if".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider such questions on-topic, as long as they ask about one specific political philosophy (just like in the stated example).

Examples I would **not consider on-topic**

> Could redistribution of property in the Americas be considered just?

What's just and what isn't is **Primarily opinion-based**.

> With respect to which political philosophies could any distribution of property in the Americas be considered just?

First, **too broad**, because there are too many different political philosophies. Second, invitation to soap boxing about one's favorite political ideology.

Regarding hypothetical examples: Political philosophies are usually theoretical models, so I would consider both hypothetical examples and real-world application on-topic.

Hypothetical examples must of course include all the details which are required to properly fit them into the model of the philosophy. This might require some back-and-forth asking in form of comments to get the question author to add the details they might not yet know are relevant in that philosophy.

Comment: Questions about facts of a political philosophy would be on topic.  Questions that ask how a philosophy has been applied or could be applied to a specific real world circumstance or even one one that is hypothetical but realistic should be on topic as well.  Its when you get into the predictions of how effective it would be or the judgement of if it would be beneficial that the questions become problematic.